# How to pass simple string to cucumber-jvm stepdef in latest 4.x version

Tags: java, string, cucumber-jvm

In the feature file I have the following (Joe is the parameter I would like to pass to the step file)

```
   Given Person name is Joe
```

In the steps file, I wrote :

```
@Given("Person name is {string1}")
    public void personName(String name) {
        System.out.println("name=" +name);
    }
```

In the class which implements TypeRegistryConfigurer, I wrote

```
typeRegistry.defineParameterType(new ParameterType<String>(
        "string1",
        "([^ ']*)",
        String.class,
        new Transformer<String>() {
            @Override
            public String transform(String s) throws Throwable {
                return s;
            }
        })
);
```

I can't define **defineParameterType** with name=*{string}*. I get an error that it is already defined, but If I use *{string}* in the steps the *Given* is undefined.
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When matching strings, your step has to enclose the parameter value in quotes (single or double) (see https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/#parameter-types )

So, change your story line to :

```
Given Person name is "Joe"
```

Then you can use the step definition :

```
@Given("Person name is {string}")
public void personName(String name) {
    System.out.println("name=" +name);
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to paste in the current text of that line in the feature file.

Comment: Great - that looks OK.  Have you had success with running any steps ?   Could you also edit the question to add any cucumber settings - eg, the @CucumberOptions on the class, or if you've set command line options, etc.

Comment: Do you know what additional pre-defined properties do we have except {int} and {string}   ?

Comment: Glad it's working :)   From that page I linked to, there's also `{float}`, '`{word}` (like string, but no spaces), and `{}` (anything).